# Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :giver_id, :scope => :account_id
end

add_index(:gifts, [:account_id, :giver_id], :uniq => true)
```

Action

```
def create
  @gift= Gift.new(params[:gift])

  if @gift.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

In the "production" mode, I sometimes get an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '122394471958-50301499' for key 'index_gifts_on_account_id_and_user_id'
```

What the problem?

Comment: what is params[:gift] value in your example ?

Comment: {:account_id => "122394471958", :giver_id => "50301499"}

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `gifts` table has an unique index for `account_id` and `user_id`.

Add an uniqueness check to your model if you need this index:

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :giver_id, :scope => :account_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :account_id
end
```

Otherwise drop the index.

```
DROP INDEX index_gifts_on_account_id_and_user_id ON gifts
```

**Edit:**
 Try adding a presence check for `giver_id`.

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :giver_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :account_id
end
```

Comment: I am wrong write my error

Is is

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '122394471958-50301499' for key 'index_gifts_on_account_id_and_giver_id'