# Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model

```
class Gift < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :giver_id, :scope => :account_id
end

add_index(:gifts, [:account_id, :giver_id], :uniq => true)
```

Action

```
def create
  @gift= Gift.new(params[:gift])

  if @gift.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

In the "production" mode, I sometimes get an error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '122394471958-50301499' for key 'index_gifts_on_account_id_and_giver_id'
```

What the problem?

Comment: Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605625/mysqlerror-duplicate-entry for Duplicate Entry. lol :)

Answer (score 1):

Your is made of two values :account_id and :giver_id. If you say :unique => true on your index that means that you are expecting the combination of :account_id and :giver_id to yield a unique value which will be inserted into the index.